# Firebase field names are automatically changed?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

Hello firebase started automatically changing my field names, this creates a big problem

How can I solve this problem:

[image: screenshot tree element]

My Class

```
    public class TUser {
        private String UserKey;
        private String LicenceKey;
        private String UserName;
        private Boolean Active;
        private String LoginDateTime;
        private String InstanceId;
        private String AcenteAdi;
        private String Version;
        private String MethodName;

        public TUser() {
        }

        public TUser(String userKey, String licenceKey, String userName, Boolean active, String loginDateTime, String instanceId, String acenteAdi, String version, String methodName) {
            UserKey = userKey;
            LicenceKey = licenceKey;
            UserName = userName;
            Active = active;
            LoginDateTime = loginDateTime;
            InstanceId = instanceId;
            AcenteAdi = acenteAdi;
            Version = version;
            MethodName = methodName;
        }

// ************ get set etc ****

    }
```

Comment: I found the source of the problem. if I select minifyEnabled true in gradle, application size from 6 mb to 2mb size is getting smaller

in this case the class names I send to firebase are shortened, which is very strange, and I think it's an error, it makes me get an error when I need to read the data again





    android {
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled true
            }
        }
    }

Comment: If the solution in your comment solved the problem, add it as an answer so other future users can see it.

Comment: @alex-mamo system auto blocked reply could not add

Comment: Why do you say that? :|

Comment: this error pops up when you press the answer button
;
We are no longer accepting answers from this account. See the Help Center to learn more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have Changed `minifyEnabled` from `true` to `false` in build.gradle(module)

```
minifyEnabled: false
```

and That works for me...!