# Why does firebase not insert data correctly on other devices?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

So example of my database is below

[image: Example of data being inserted wrong]

So on other devices the data being inserted is the node on the bottom, while
the way I want my data to be inserted is the node thats above.

Below is my code for the registration

```
mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass)
.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
        if(task.isSuccessful()) {

            System.out.println("registered student");

            Students students = new Students(user, pass, sections,teachers,email,"yes","no","no","no","no","no");

            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Students")
                    .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).setValue(students).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                    if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Student has been registered!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        Intent i = new Intent(Register.this, StudentLogin.class);

                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Failed to register!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }
            });
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Failed to register student! Try again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
});
```

On a side note I also send the apk through firebase app distribution apk and when they register though their phone the bottom node on the image is the one being inserted

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. Your code writes the data under the UID of the signed in user. Is that not what you want?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen yes but on the bottom node it only inserts the userName into the database not the other child nodes

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen for some reason when on other peoples devices i send the apk through firebase app distrib and it only gives me the userName data and the childnode name is also wrong as u can see it only displays a: not userName:

Comment: Aha, that is probably because you didn't configure ProGuard/M8 correct in the release version of your app. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/58518010, https://stackoverflow.com/q/50292125, and https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start#proguard

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen ty! i solved it by both disabling minifyEnabled and shrinkResources